# manage javascript data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I have a site that gets a user data on logging in.
this data is saved by mysql as a string, and after calling this string with ajax, I split the data by js function: str.split().
this returns an array with all the id's of the btns I would like to check, and with the ".each" call I check all matched btns.
the big problem is that this process takes about 10 seconds on local server.
is there a better and faster way to get user data?
p.s: we talk about hundreds of btns on user login.

here is the code:

```
function get_saved_list(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/get_saved_list.php",
        success: function(data){
            list=data.split(";");
            for(j=0; j<list.length-1; j++){
                $(".content #"+list[j]).siblings('a').trigger('click');
            }
            setTimeout("$('#save').hide()", 1);
        }
    });     
}
```

some of the html include the 'a' that is triggered:

```
<ul class="content"><li>
<a class="third_cat_chb cat_chb_off"></a><span>page</span>
                                        <button id="page_<?php echo $row['page']."Z"; ?>chapter_<?php echo $row['s_id'];?>" style="width: 20px; margin-right: 5px;" class="page_chooser"></button></li></ul>
```

sory for the bad format : )

Comment: _hundreds of btns on user login_ ... are you serious?

Comment: do you multiple buttons with the same id? where is the 10 seconds being spent? is it waiting on the ajax? or the checking of the buttons? can you please include a sample of the html?

Comment: How much of that time is the ajax download, and how much of it is the loop through the IDs?

Comment: The problem is on the server side i am sure. show how youy are saving the data. Also, usually login is just one button

Comment: can you also include the jquery for those a 's that you are triggering clicks for?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you really should replace `setTimeout("$('#save').hide()", 1);` with `setTimeout(function(){$('#save').hide()}, 1);` ([why?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)).

Comment: I am series.. there maybe up to 680 checked btns..
every checked btn increase the time of loading the page.. with no btns checked, it takes less than second. when there are about 150 btns, it takes 10 seconds.
there is no multiple is (sure not : ). I use an id with 2 data: page number and chapter number and separate then with "Z".
I would mention also that this is not a server problem: the data takes meleseconds to load.. the problem is in the jquery or in the huge number of btns.
I will edit my question to add the html:

Comment: Why are you leaking globals? Please read about the `var` keyboard. Protip: `for(var j = 0; ...)` and `var list = ...`

Comment: That's way too many elements to be dealing with in my opinion. I suggest working your logic in the direction of having less active buttons at a time to work with, for example, only loading 1 "chapter" at a time.

Comment: What happens when you click the anchors? What does `$(".content #"+list[j]).siblings('a').trigger('click');` do?

Comment: when I click on the anchors, a lot of things happen..
when I removed what happens, the response was decreased down to 5 seconds, so there is something in your opinion..

Comment: Why are you triggering a click event on hundreds of links? I can't think of any problem that this would be the right way to solve. I'm not saying there isn't one, but I would bet that there's a better solution that just doesn't involve firing hundreds of events.

Comment: I would bet too. I am sure there is an answer somewhere : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't prefix your ID selector with a class. This prohibits jQuery from using the native getElementById(), and instead uses getElementsByClassName(), which is slower.

Try this selector instead: `$("#"+list[j])`

I was able to loop through 1000 items and trigger a click in about 1 second, rather than 4-5 seconds by doing a class first.

It would also help if you could put an ID on the actual `<a>` that you want to click so that you can avoid the call to siblings(), which adds additional overhead.

Comment: ok. the idea of putting in id to the <a> saved me 3 seconds : )
but I was looking for a stronger solution..
thanks jordan

Comment: ok. the idea of putting in id to the <a> saved me a lot of time.
I added an id to this <a> and also decided to cut many of the "functions" when clicking this btn. instead, I add the last result to the DB and get it back on the last click event..
now I have about 3 seconds on loading the page, thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

If you've got control over the server it would save a huge amount of time to use the `checked="true"` html attribute, setting it conditionally in php instead of triggering a click event.

If you're stuck with Javascript: I'm not sure, but it might also be faster to set the `checked` property than to click it, since you wouldn't then also be triggering a "click" event.

```
$("#"+list[j]).siblings('a').attr('checked');
```

should work, although I haven't tested it.

Really though, if you can, setting it on the server is the way to go.

Comment: It's a link. Why would it have a checked attribute?

Comment: Wow, I totally misread the code after reading the word "check" twenty times in the question and I thought that he was trying to check some checkboxes. Because why would someone be programmatically clicking hundreds of links? I'm probably going to delete this answer.

Comment: I click hundreds of btns because every click would make changes to a lot of data on the page.
every btn must be clicked and every checked btn would affect the other btns, so, yes, there is a reason for these clicks!

Comment: But, *why*: what kinds of data modification does it do? Are you doing some sort of visualization using number of link clicks to affect page color? Are you modifying some data structure on every `click` event? I can't think of a situation where doing things directly wouldn't be faster than clicking hundreds of links. What is your situation? "Hundreds" is practically zero, in computational terms. You should be able to do all of this in less than 50ms. 4-5 seconds is *likely* absurd, and suggests that you're thinking about your data or algorithm incorrectly.